# Easy way to assign function keys to Dialog?

Tags: mfc

I have a MFC dialog and I would like to assign function keys to different methods. Is that possible?

For example I would like to type F9 and have the same result as pressing a button.

Answer (score 3):

For Dialog Based application. Create a IDR_ACCELERATOR1 in resource editor for your dialog. And add the Key you wanted and create a Event for the Key for your dialog.

In  sampledlg.h please add

```
HACCEL m_haccel;
```

In  sampledlg.cpp In OnInitDialog() please add

```
m_haccel = LoadAccelerators(AfxGetInstanceHandle(), MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDR_ACCELERATOR1));
```

In  sampledlg.cpp In PreTranslateMessage(MSG *pMsg) please add

```
if (m_haccel)
{
  if ((::TranslateAccelerator(*this, m_haccel, pMsg))) 
  {    
      return(TRUE);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you mean in the main dialog of a dialog based application, you can check
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/37130/Implement-Accelerators-in-a-Dialog-Based-Applicati.aspx

If it's for dialogs in a doc/view application:
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/117500/en-us

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/222829/en-us

Answer (score 1):

Easier than I thought. I don't know if this is the best solution but this is what I did:

```
BOOL MainDlg::PreTranslateMessage(MSG *pMsg)
{   
  if ( pMsg->message == WM_KEYDOWN)
  {
     if (( pMsg->wParam == VK_F9))
       OnBnClickedButton1(); // Delete Item
 }

  return CDialog::PreTranslateMessage(pMsg);
}
```

Now, every time Function Key F9 is pressed function OnBClickedButton1() is called.